# Issue with ext4.vhdx using WSL2 in Windows 11

Tags: partitioning, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ext4, windows-11

I had and issue with WSL installing a package, so I decided to uninstall Ubuntu 22.04 to fresh install again. I did the mistake to delete manually some files and then I had some issues to reinstall Ubuntu, it displayed an error: there was no file in `C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu22.04LTS_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\ext4.vhdx`.

Finally I was able to installed, and later I wanted to inspect the folder to see what is inside, and seems to be empty. Is that correct? Now my Ubuntu terminal runs correctly. I updated packages, open Python3 in the terminal open Visual Studio Code from WSL, but overall I have the feeling that something is wrong.

Another thing is that when I go to the Linux folder, there are two Ubuntu folders, and when I try to access Ubuntu 22.04 it does not allow me. Before I just had one Ubuntu in that location.

[image: Ubuntu folder in Windows]

Comment: Just as a side note : I encountered the same and I didn't try to manually delete files. It occurred after a failed update as it seems.

NotTheDr01ds's answer with the `wsl --unregister distro` command worked just as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At this point, it seems that you have two "distributions" still "registered", as far as WSL understands.  You can see the list of distributions with:

```
wsl.exe -l -v
```

I'm assuming that this list matches your screenshot:

- `Ubuntu`
- `Ubuntu-22.04`

Given that the package location for 22.04 is empty, I'm also assuming that this was the first one you installed and the one that you manually deleted.

I know it sounds like I'm repeating myself (and your question), and that's because the command to fix this is **destructive** and irreversible, so *please* make sure that you are removing the right one (if you have any files in the other that are important).

Assuming that `Ubuntu` works and `Ubuntu-22.04` doesn't:

```
# Warning:  destructive operation
wsl --unregister Ubuntu-22.04
```

That should remove the registration for the one that you removed manually.

Comment: Many thanks for this reply, I do not have any important files there, so I will follow this instructions. Greetings!

Comment: Many thanks for your help! I fixed it following the commands you posted. Greetings!